# How to import config file from folder in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am creating nestjs project in which I have `config` folder which has config files based on environments like local, staging, or production. I want to import this file into another file but when I am trying to do so its showing error:

Below is my files:

**config/config-local.t2**

```
export const env = 'local';
export const databases = {
 mongodb_url: 'mongodb://localhost/truckload',
 es_url: 'http://localhost:9200'
};
export const logConfig = {
 path : '/Users/services/example.log',
};
```

Now I want to import mongodb_url in a different file for that I am importing something like this

```
import { databases } from '../config/config-local.t2';
```

But it's showing an error below importing statement. How can I import database property from the config file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you using the `.t2` format for a config file, however, for such importing you must change the config file format to `.ts` to be a valid **TypeScript** format. Then, the `import` statement will be like this:

```
import { databases } from '../config/config-local';
```